# Match Case option missing in Pycharm search

Tags: pycharm

I have been using Pycharm for some time now and noticed that in the current version I am using (Community 2021.1.1) the Match Case tickbox is missing (probably is hidden).

I found it really useful from time to time to restrict the search in some contexts so I miss this option.

How can I re-enable this option in my version, any ideas?

Version 2021: [image]

Older version (with *Match Case* present): [image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, so they just change it to a different button and moved it a bit to the left:
[image]

The *Cc* button correspond to Match Case tickbox.

Comment: The `Cc` notation likely relates to Camel Case, although that would usually be `cC` rather than `Cc`